# pyqt4 - Default padding between elements in vboxlayout?

Tags: python, qt, layout, pyqt4

What is the default padding between elements in a vboxlayout? I measured it myself and found 10px, but was wondering if this is documented somewhere (I could not find it using google search).

Also, how can I make elements line up perfectly, if, for instance, I have a vbox inside of an hbox? I tried to subtract pixels from the heights of the elements in the vbox to account for a 10px padding, but found that it still did not line up perfectly. For instance, I had two elements so I subtracted 5 pixels from each of the heights. How can I get these to line up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default values for the padding are dependent on the current widget style.

The padding *between* elements can be retrieved using the [spacing](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#spacing) method. But you may also need to take account of the margins, which can be retrieved with [getContentsMargins](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlayout.html#getContentsMargins) (which returns a tuple of four values in PyQt).

Of course, you can also set the spacing and margins to whatever values you like.

**UPDATE**:

It seems that `getContentsMargins` only returns the default values when the layout has a widget parent. The values may also differ for top-level layouts, which tend to have slightly larger values.

For `spacing`, it seems that `-1` will always be returned if the layout does not have a parent. If it does have a parent, it should eventually return the appropriate value form the parent widget's style.

However, when I try:

```
    widget.style().pixelMetric(QtGui.QStyle.PM_LayoutVerticalSpacing)
```

I still get `-1`, which is baffling, to say the least...

**EDIT**:

I can get reliable values on WinXP, but not on Linux when using a custom widget style (which presumably has a little bug somewhere).

Comment: Interesting... I called spacing() and getContentsMargins() on my vbox and got -1 and (0,0,0,0)... however there is definitely a positive spacing between elements. Am I calling the methods on the wrong thing?

Comment: @mage. It may depend on _when_ you call them, because they are calculated properties. Hard to diagnose properly without seeing actual code, though.

Comment: @mage. Actually, even with a very simple example, I have so far struggled to get these methods to reliably return useful default values. I will have to investigate further...

Comment: Yes, putting it at the very end of my code gave me 7 and (0,0,0,0), so I went with 7. Ideally I could get the default and simply subtract that variable from the height of an element to make them line up. Unless you know of a better way to force elements to line up?

Comment: @mage. I'm not sure what you mean by "line up". Can you post a screenshot, or some code to show what you mean?

Comment: I put some screenshots in this album: http://imgur.com/a/KMwWF First two images, the vbox on the left is not lined up with qframe on the right. Last image it is lined up perfectly. There are 3 clearly marked qframes in each image. Image descriptions give the dimensions of each QFrame.

Comment: @mage. Is it really necessary to set fixed dimensions? What happens when the window is resized? It's much better to [set a stretch factor](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#setStretch) for the widgets and avoid absolute sizes altogether.